# scala pattern matching nested cases

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I try to `match` after some `case` applied. Kind of `nested cases/matches`:

```
val x1 = 2 // or 1, 3 ...
val str = x1 match {   // scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Integer)

  case x if(x > 1) => "x"+x match {case "x1" => "yes"}

  // updated:
  case _ => "nope"
}
println (str)
```

It fails with `scala.MatchError` exception.

Is it possible? It seems I've seen something similar.

> Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: x2 (of class
>   java.lang.String)     at
>   pattern_matching.PatternMatchingTest$delayedInit$body.apply(PatternMatchingTest.scala:32)
>     at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)   at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are hitting is that your example input (`val x1 = 1`) doesn't match the one case you gave (since x1 is not greater than 1). You will need to either modify your existing case (eg. change the if to something like `if(x >= 1)`) or add at least one more case, and should probably consider a default case. eg.:

```
val str = x1 match {   // scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Integer)
  case x if(x > 1) => "x"+x match {case "x1" => "yes"}
  case _ => "no match"
}
```

Comment: even if 2 (just was experimenting)

Comment: Yes, because now you fail in the second match ("x2" != "x1")

Comment: Hm.. strange it managed get success after second compile. At least I glad that it works like I expected in terms of syntax.